# не могу построить 2 графика google charts

Tags: php, javascript

Суть вопроса такова, я подготовил несколько графиков через google charts и они у меня прекрасно выводились на одной странице, но в какой-то момент стал появляться только один график-первый, подскажите в чем может быть затык. 
Ниже привожу код:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Возраст', 'Низкий уровень', 'Средний уровень', 'Высокий уровень'],
      ['13',  <?php  echo  $nizkiy13; ?>,    <?php  echo  $stredniy13; ?>,    <?php  echo  $visokiy13; ?> ],
         ['14',  <?php  echo  $nizkiy14; ?>,    <?php  echo  $stredniy14; ?>,    <?php  echo  $visokiy14; ?> ],
             ['15',  <?php  echo  $nizkiy15; ?>,    <?php  echo  $stredniy15; ?>,    <?php  echo  $visokiy15; ?> ],
                     ['16',  <?php  echo  $nizkiy16; ?>,    <?php  echo  $stredniy16; ?>,    <?php  echo  $visokiy16; ?> ],
             ['17',  <?php  echo  $nizkiy17; ?>,    <?php  echo  $stredniy17; ?>,    <?php  echo  $visokiy17; ?> ],
                     ['18',  <?php  echo  $nizkiy18; ?>,    <?php  echo  $stredniy18; ?>,    <?php  echo  $visokiy18; ?> ]

    ]);

    var options = {
      title: 'График 1',
      hAxis: {title: '<?php  echo  $rayon; ?>',  titleTextStyle: {color: '#333'}},
      vAxis: {minValue: 0}
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
</script>







  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.charts.load('current2', {'packages':['corechart2']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart2);
  function drawChart2() {
    var data2 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Возраст', 'Низкий уровень', 'Средний уровень', 'Высокий уровень'],
     ['13',  <?php  echo  $nizkiyg13; ?>,    <?php  echo  $stredniyg13; ?>,    <?php  echo  $visokiyg13; ?> ],
         ['14',  <?php  echo  $nizkiyg14; ?>,    <?php  echo  $stredniyg14; ?>,    <?php  echo  $visokiyg14; ?> ],
             ['15',  <?php  echo  $nizkiyg15; ?>,    <?php  echo  $stredniyg15; ?>,    <?php  echo  $visokiyg15; ?> ],
                     ['16',  <?php  echo  $nizkiyg16; ?>,    <?php  echo  $stredniyg16; ?>,    <?php  echo  $visokiyg16; ?> ],
             ['17',  <?php  echo  $nizkiyg17; ?>,    <?php  echo  $stredniyg17; ?>,    <?php  echo  $visokiyg17; ?> ],
                     ['18',  <?php  echo  $nizkiyg18; ?>,    <?php  echo  $stredniyg18; ?>,    <?php  echo  $visokiyg18; ?> ]


    ]);

    var options2 = {
      title: 'График 2',
      hAxis: {title: '<?php  echo  $rayon; ?>',  titleTextStyle: {color: '#333'}},
      vAxis: {minValue: 0}
    };

    var chart2 = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div2'));
    chart2.draw(data2, options2);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: js ошибок в консоли нет?

Comment: без php вставок привели бы код.

Comment: function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Возраст', 'Низкий уровень', 'Средний уровень', 'Высокий уровень'],
      ['13',  '155', '144'],
      ['13',  '145', '149']
    ]);

    var options = {
      title: 'График 1',
      hAxis: {title: 'график 1',  titleTextStyle: {color: '#333'}},
      vAxis: {minValue: 0}
    };

 без php функция будет выглядеть так. Весь код не удалось вставить, поскольку ограничение на ввод стоит

Comment: в js ошибок нет, отдельно друг от друга графики выводятся.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того, что бы создать два/несколько графиков на одной странице, необходимо:
1. в `head` загрузить все пакеты в `google.charts.load()`.
2. для каждой диаграммы на странице добавить вызов.

`google.charts.setOnLoadCallback() (например: google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(myPieChart))`

Вот готовый код двух графиков на одной странице:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      // Load Charts and the corechart package.
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});

      // Draw the pie chart for Sarah's pizza when Charts is loaded.
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawSarahChart);

      // Draw the pie chart for the Anthony's pizza when Charts is loaded.
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawAnthonyChart);

      // Callback that draws the pie chart for Sarah's pizza.
      function drawSarahChart() {

        // Create the data table for Sarah's pizza.
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');
        data.addRows([
          ['Mushrooms', 1],
          ['Onions', 1],
          ['Olives', 2],
          ['Zucchini', 2],
          ['Pepperoni', 1]
        ]);

        // Set options for Sarah's pie chart.
        var options = {title:'How Much Pizza Sarah Ate Last Night',
                       width:400,
                       height:300};

        // Instantiate and draw the chart for Sarah's pizza.
        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('Sarah_chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }

      // Callback that draws the pie chart for Anthony's pizza.
      function drawAnthonyChart() {

        // Create the data table for Anthony's pizza.
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');
        data.addRows([
          ['Mushrooms', 2],
          ['Onions', 2],
          ['Olives', 2],
          ['Zucchini', 0],
          ['Pepperoni', 3]
        ]);

        // Set options for Anthony's pie chart.
        var options = {title:'How Much Pizza Anthony Ate Last Night',
                       width:400,
                       height:300};

        // Instantiate and draw the chart for Anthony's pizza.
        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('Anthony_chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!--Table and divs that hold the pie charts-->
    <table class="columns">
      <tr>
        <td><div id="Sarah_chart_div" style="border: 1px solid #ccc"></div></td>
        <td><div id="Anthony_chart_div" style="border: 1px solid #ccc"></div></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Да ребята, все эти вопросы и многие другие Вы можете прочитать [тут](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/).

Специально для "ленивых" разработчики постарались разжевать материал.

Comment: Вопрос решил, но все равно, благодарю за детальный ответ.